# Insert Data from SQL Server to MySql using Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have two databases, one is in SQL Server and other is in MySql. I want to insert data into MySQL table while an insertion occurs in the SQL Server table. Is it possible using a trigger in SQL Server? Please give me an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create connection from `MSSQL` to `MySQL` by going through [this article on connecting MSSQL to MySQL](http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/).

After successfully creating connection from `MSSQL` to `MySQL`, you can write trigger to insert data in MySQL database using INSERT query in your trigger.

Hope it helps...