# How to update ms sql database after insert data on mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a database on mysql (request from applestore) and now I must rewrite one table to ms sql. It's easy to rewrtie old rows, but when new row appear on mysql I need get this to ms sql table, and I don't know how to connect this and do it. Someone can hel me?

Comment: what is youre approach? to synchronize mysql to ms sql ? or to rewrite mysql querries to ms sql?

Comment: If you're looking at migration you might get more help on http://dba.stackexchange.com/, your problem doesn't seem to be a programming one, unless you intend on creating an application to do this. Your description isn't exactly clear but you might be looking at `triggers` or `jobs`, if you clarify your actual requirements maybe with a descriptive example you might get more help :)

Comment: I tried to use linked server and it's works to rewrtie data from mysql

Comment: If you're looking at going cross-platform you are probably looking for a more in-depth and specialized solution which is why I pointed out you should look at dba.stackexchange.com as there are more database specialists there (this is more code). You might require the implementation of a trigger which sets off an SSIS package with the required data; without a more detailed description of your requirements, all we can do is point you at resources or spout key-words for you to google (and your English is fine by the way).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replication from MySQL to MS SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455018/replication-from-mysql-to-ms-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with triggers??..you need to create a trigger which insert the same data in a table when it is inserted in another table.

Comment: I know that I need trigger but how to create trigger in mysql which will fire insert on ms sql server database?

Comment: please have a look at this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080765/insert-data-from-mssql-to-mysql-using-trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080765/insert-data-from-mssql-to-mysql-using-trigger)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.